# MySQL: Extract complete node from XML document

Tags: mysql, xml, xpath, mysql-5.7

I'm working with XML in MySQL, and I need to extract a node from a larger XML document, complete with attributes and children. The full XML is something like this:

```
<parent>
    <child
        attrOne="1"
        attrTwo="two">
        <grandchild 
            attrThree="3"
            attrFour="four"
        />
    </child>
</parent>
```

And what I'm trying to obtain would be:

```
<child
    attrOne="1"
    attrTwo="two">
    <grandchild 
        attrThree="3"
        attrFour="four"
    />
</child>
```

Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this? I know about `ExtractValue()`, but that's supposed to get only the value of a node and not the node itself.